# How is an operator $F$ called for which for every $x$ a function $F_x$ exists with $F(f)(x) = F_x(f(x))$?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $F$ be an operator on a function space $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{Y}^\mathcal{X}$.
How is an operator $F$ called for which for every $x \in \mathcal{X}$ a function $F_x$ exists with $F(f)(x) = F_x(f(x))$? (i.e. what properties of $F$ are sufficient to guarantee the existence of $F_x$)

Answer (score 0):

I would claim that if we assume that $F$ has to be a linear operator with your property
$$
\exists F_x : \mathcal Y \to \mathcal Y \text{ such that}: F(f)(x) = F_x(f(x)) \quad \forall x \in \mathcal X, \, f \in \mathcal H
$$
then $F_x$ must be a linear map.

To see this, we first define for $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ the corresponding constant function as $f_y : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y} : x \mapsto y$.

Then we can define
$$
A(x) y := F_x( y ) = F(f_y)(x).
$$

This is a linear map, since by linearity of $F$ we get
$$
A(x) (\lambda_1 y_1 + y_2) = F(f_{\lambda_1 y_1 + y_2})(x) = \lambda_1 F(f_{y_1} )(x) + F(f_{y_2})(x) = \lambda_1 A(x) y_1 + A(x) y_2.
$$

So, for every linear operator $F$ with your condition, we know that it must satisfy
$$
F(f) = A(x) f(x)
$$
for some function $A : \mathcal{X} \to \mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{Y})$.

Vice versa, if we take an arbitrary $B : \mathcal{X} \to \mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{Y})$ and define
$$
G(f)(x) := B(x) f(x)
$$
then this will be a linear map $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ since
$$
G(\lambda f + g)(x) = B(x)( \lambda f(x) + g(x) ) = \lambda G(f)(x) + G(g)(x).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm looking for a property of $F$ that guarantees the existence of $F_x$. Unfortunately, there are linear operators for which this does not hold. (For example, if $\mathcal{H}$ is the set of smooth functions and $F$ is the differentiation operator)

Comment: I see. Maybe you could specify your setting a bit further. If you restrict yourself to the case $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{R}$ then you essentially have a [multiplication operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_operator). Already here it makes a big difference if you consider $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ or other function spaces, since then it is not clear that the image is contained in $L^2$, that effectively leads to a condition on the regularity of $x \mapsto F_x$. See for example: https://revistas.unal.edu.co/index.php/bolma/article/view/62239/63295